# Layout change after page 2

Tags: xsl-fo

I need to produce invoices that have a payment slip on the bottom of the first page. On the back of that first page the text must not go into the payment slip area on the front.
From the the next page on, the whole page size must be used for the text.

Is this possible with xsl-fo? I couldn't figure a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use an `fo:page-sequence-master`.  See

- https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence-master
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e7070
- "Switching the layout in facing pages automatically (page-sequence-master)" in https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/

Something like:

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="psm">
  <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="page1"/>
  <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="page2"/>
  <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="the-rest"/>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

where `page` is the `fo:simple-page-master` for the first page, `page2` is for the second page, and `the-rest` is for the rest.

You'd have to set the `margin-bottom` on either `page2` or its `fo:region-body` so that no content goes behind the payslip.

The most portable way to do the payslip on `page1` would be to put its content in the `fo:static-content` for the `fo:region-after` of `page1`.  If your formatter supports multiple `fo:region-body` then you could put the content in a second `fo:flow` to flow into a second `fo:region-body`.  If you are using AH Formatter, you could use either of those techniques or you could put the payslip content in an `fo:float` and make it float to the bottom of the page.

Comment: We had used 'fo:conditional-page-master-reference' for some other reasons, which I have to find out if they are still relevant or not.
If not, your solution should work perfect.

Comment: You might have been using `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_conditional-page-master-reference) to get different page layouts; for example, to have different headers or footers on odd and even pages or a different page layout for the last page. You could put a `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` containing multiple `fo:conditional-page-master-alternatives` in place of the `fo:repeatable-page-master-reference`.  The formatter would use the first two page masters for the first two pages then choose the first matching alternative for any following pages.